# Drools rule to check that sublist is contained in a list

Tags: drools

I want to be able to check if at least one element from a list of string elements (see $el.getTags()) is contained in a list (tagService.getAvailableTags($el.getName()) using a Drools rule. I'm using a helper method for the check: CollectionUtils.containsValuesFromList(subList, targetList, checkAllValues).

For now I'm using below rule definition:

```
rule "Check at least one tag is set"
when
   $el: Element()
   $tags : tagService.getTags($el.getName())
   $errors : ValidationErrors()
   $condition: CollectionUtils.containsValueFromList($el.getTags(), $tags, true)
then
   $errors.addError( $el, "el", "At least one tag should be set!");
end
```

Could it be possible to check if at least one sub list element is contained in a list,  without using any helper method?
 Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Updated with question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rule "Check at least one tag is set"
when
$el: Element()
$tags : tagService.getTags($el.getName())
$errors : ValidationErrors()
//  $condition: CollectionUtils.containsValueFromList($el.getTags(), $tags, true)
Element( Tags in ($tags) )
then
$errors.addError( $el, "el", "At least one tag should be set!");
end
```